# How to clear an .appendChild in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created a tip calculator.  After you put in the amount and hit enter text pops up telling you how much you owe if you pay 20%.  I figured out how to clear the numbers in the `<input>` but I can't figure out the JS so that the text clears as well.

This is a link to my file.

https://codepen.io/wrraybin/pen/WVdvLN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Tip Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='tip-calc.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
      <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
        <form id='tip-calc'>
            <input id='enter-num' type='number' placeholder='Bill Total' name='tipTotal' >
           <div id='buttons'>
            <button id='butt-one'>Tip</button>
           <input id='butt-two' type="reset" value="Reset" name='resetButton'>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='final-amount'>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="tip-calc.js"></script>
</html>

document.querySelector('#tip-calc').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    document.querySelector('#final-amount').innerHTML = ''
    const billTotal = document.createElement('h2')
    const tip = Math.floor( e.target.elements.tipTotal.value * 0.2)
    billTotal.textContent = `You should leave $${tip} if tipping 20%.`
    document.querySelector('#final-amount').appendChild(billTotal)
 })
```

Comment: ```child.remove()``` will un-append it. Other than that your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your help.  I apologize if the question wasn't clear.  This is my first post and I'm still kind of new to coding.

Comment: @Wrrigley You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener on the reset button and on click reset the Html in the final-amount div

```js
document.querySelector('#butt-two').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      document.querySelector('#final-amount').innerHTML = ''
})
```

Comment: 21x37, Thank you.  I tried your code and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to file tip-calc.js

```
document.querySelector('#butt-two').onclick =  
  () => document.querySelector('#final-amount').innerHTML = '';
```

```js
document.querySelector('#tip-calc').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  document.querySelector('#final-amount').innerHTML = ''
  const billTotal = document.createElement('h2')
  const tip = Math.floor(e.target.elements.tipTotal.value * 0.2)
  billTotal.textContent = `You should leave $${tip} if tipping 20%.`
  document.querySelector('#final-amount').appendChild(billTotal)
})

document.querySelector('#butt-two').onclick =  
  () => document.querySelector('#final-amount').innerHTML = '';
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  <form id='tip-calc'>
    <input id='enter-num' type='number' placeholder='Bill Total' name='tipTotal'>
    <div id='buttons'>
      <button id='butt-one'>Tip</button>
      <input id='butt-two' type="reset" value="Reset" name='resetButton'>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id='final-amount'>

</div>
```

Comment: Kamil, thank you for your help.  It worked perfectly.